# Ошибка: 429 при использовании сервиса https://static-maps.yandex.ru/1.x

Tags: yandex-static-maps-api

При вызове запроса получаю ошибку:Server returned HTTP response code: 429 for URL

Запрос
[https://static-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?l=map,trf&pl=w:3,45.716646,48.588738,45.716614,48.588661,45.716566,48.588629,45.71653,48.588629,45.716306,48.588673,45.71627,48.588673,45.716222,48.588642,45.716121,48.588409,45.7161,48.588361,45.716664,48.588262,45.716863,48.588227,45.716883,48.588223,45.716945,48.588212,45.717474,48.588088,45.718828,48.587854,45.720182,48.587618,45.720391,48.58758,45.721573,48.587359,45.721573,48.587359,45.721446,48.587047,45.721309,48.586719,45.721283,48.586654,45.720787,48.585453,45.72066,48.585144,45.720458,48.584649,45.720437,48.584591,45.720398,48.584495,45.719615,48.582552,45.719202,48.581528,45.71879,48.580505,45.718763,48.580439,45.718387,48.579497,45.718334,48.579405,45.718245,48.579323,45.718084,48.57919,45.717948,48.579064,45.71786,48.578997,45.717552,48.578845,45.717163,48.578539,45.717119,48.578479,45.716524,48.577662,45.715929,48.576846,45.716333,48.576648,45.717651,48.575995,45.718112,48.575775,45.718847,48.575492,45.719181,48.575397,45.71945,48.57534,45.71982,48.575279,45.720754,48.575216,45.721343,48.575193,45.721796,48.575199,45.725388,48.575324,45.72752,48.575408,45.729652,48.575493,45.730752,48.575648,45.731618,48.575828,45.732184,48.575936,45.73251,48.575969,45.733427,48.575941,45.734006,48.575862,45.734646,48.575752,45.735192,48.575641,45.735714,48.575538,45.736078,48.575468,45.736454,48.575409,45.73671,48.575394,45.737413,48.57537,45.737987,48.575365,45.738572,48.575365,45.740536,48.575374,45.740944,48.575396,45.741181,48.575405,45.741878,48.575459,45.74281,48.575559,45.743562,48.575624,45.74422,48.5757,45.744348,48.575713,45.744396,48.575808,45.744416,48.575917,45.744452,48.576149,45.744567,48.576891,45.744693,48.577342,45.744715,48.577421,45.744862,48.57778,45.74692,48.577289,45.747823,48.577073,45.748611,48.576884,45.750442,48.576432,45.751661,48.576129,45.75182,48.57609,45.753624,48.575642,45.753986,48.575506,45.755215,48.574903,45.755413,48.574805,45.756094,48.57449,45.757122,48.574019,45.757727,48.573742,45.757963,48.572952,45.757657,48.572941&pt=45.757657,48.572941,pm2am~45.716646,48.588738,pm2bm](https://static-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?l=map,trf&pl=w:3,45.716646,48.588738,45.716614,48.588661,45.716566,48.588629,45.71653,48.588629,45.716306,48.588673,45.71627,48.588673,45.716222,48.588642,45.716121,48.588409,45.7161,48.588361,45.716664,48.588262,45.716863,48.588227,45.716883,48.588223,45.716945,48.588212,45.717474,48.588088,45.718828,48.587854,45.720182,48.587618,45.720391,48.58758,45.721573,48.587359,45.721573,48.587359,45.721446,48.587047,45.721309,48.586719,45.721283,48.586654,45.720787,48.585453,45.72066,48.585144,45.720458,48.584649,45.720437,48.584591,45.720398,48.584495,45.719615,48.582552,45.719202,48.581528,45.71879,48.580505,45.718763,48.580439,45.718387,48.579497,45.718334,48.579405,45.718245,48.579323,45.718084,48.57919,45.717948,48.579064,45.71786,48.578997,45.717552,48.578845,45.717163,48.578539,45.717119,48.578479,45.716524,48.577662,45.715929,48.576846,45.716333,48.576648,45.717651,48.575995,45.718112,48.575775,45.718847,48.575492,45.719181,48.575397,45.71945,48.57534,45.71982,48.575279,45.720754,48.575216,45.721343,48.575193,45.721796,48.575199,45.725388,48.575324,45.72752,48.575408,45.729652,48.575493,45.730752,48.575648,45.731618,48.575828,45.732184,48.575936,45.73251,48.575969,45.733427,48.575941,45.734006,48.575862,45.734646,48.575752,45.735192,48.575641,45.735714,48.575538,45.736078,48.575468,45.736454,48.575409,45.73671,48.575394,45.737413,48.57537,45.737987,48.575365,45.738572,48.575365,45.740536,48.575374,45.740944,48.575396,45.741181,48.575405,45.741878,48.575459,45.74281,48.575559,45.743562,48.575624,45.74422,48.5757,45.744348,48.575713,45.744396,48.575808,45.744416,48.575917,45.744452,48.576149,45.744567,48.576891,45.744693,48.577342,45.744715,48.577421,45.744862,48.57778,45.74692,48.577289,45.747823,48.577073,45.748611,48.576884,45.750442,48.576432,45.751661,48.576129,45.75182,48.57609,45.753624,48.575642,45.753986,48.575506,45.755215,48.574903,45.755413,48.574805,45.756094,48.57449,45.757122,48.574019,45.757727,48.573742,45.757963,48.572952,45.757657,48.572941&pt=45.757657,48.572941,pm2am%7E45.716646,48.588738,pm2bm)

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_HTTP#429

Comment: 429 Too Many Requests («слишком много запросов») — клиент попытался отправить слишком много запросов за короткое время, что может указывать, например, на попытку DDoS-атаки. Может сопровождаться заголовком Retry-After, указывающим, через какое время можно повторить запрос